# How to set background image image path in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, angular6

```html
<!----- home banner   ---->
<div class="home-slider">
  <ngx-slick class="carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
    <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
      <div class="banner">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ slide.img }}" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </ngx-slick>
</div>

<!----==== 3 content ----==================--->
<div class="dis_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-google-wallet " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h4>Discount System</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id feugiat tellus. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-codepen " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h4>Free Delivery</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id feugiat tellus. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <h4>Support 24/7</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id feugiat tellus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!---======  4 images =============------------>
<div class="ldy-page">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="ldy1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="ldy1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="ldy1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="ldy1">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<owl-carousel [options]="{items: 3, dots: false, navigation: false}" <!-- If images array is dynamically changing pass this array to [items] input -->
  [items]="images"
  <!-- classes to be attached along with owl-carousel class -->
  [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let sliding of slidings;let i = index">
    <div class="thumbnail-image" [ngStyle]="{'background': 'url('abc.jpg')no-repeat scroll center center / 80px 80px'}"></div>
  </div>
</owl-carousel>
```

How to set the image and background image path in my page? I set the image on `home.components.ts` file. How to set the background image and image path in Angular 6?

```
[{'background': 'url('abc.jpg')no-repeat scroll center center / 80px 80px'}] in ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.html@73:38 (" class="item" *ngFor="let sliding of slidings;let i = index">
```

Comment: do u use angular 6 or angularjs??

Answer (score 5):

use it to wantet selector

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ imagSource +')'"
```

in css:

```
.item{
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help!

Comment: i don't no how to set image an angular 6. so brief explain to me

Comment: in your component set in parmeter the url to image and in html use as my answer `imagSource` means the parameter from component

Answer (score 5):

Below answer worked for angular 6.

In **app.component.css**

```
    .image{
         height:40em; 
         background-size:cover;
         width:auto;
         background-image:url('copied image address');
         background-position:50% 50%;
       }
```

Also in **app.component.html** simply add as below

```
<div class="image">
Your content
</div>
```

This way I was able to set background image in Angular 6.